# InputStream чтение из файла

Tags: java, файлы, строки

Как с помощью `InputStream` прочитать файл и получить `String`?

`Java 1.7-1.8`
`NETBEANS`

Answer (score 4):

Проще всего без `InputStream`, используя [`Files.readAllBytes`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes-java.nio.file.Path-):

```
new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("c:\\путь\\к\\файлу.txt")), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Или укажите другую кодировку, какая у вас.